# Magento 2.1 - Add a new method to block class?

Tags: magento2

I need to add a new function to the configurable.php block, located in `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable`.  It's a function similar to `$block->getJsonConfig()` except it gets some different values.

Can I do this (add a new method/function) through a plugin or do I have to override the original block?  I'm not changing or removing any of the original functionality, just need to be able to call another function from the **phtml** file.  If I override, does that mean I need to copy all the original methods from the original block php or can I just define the new function I need in my override file?

Edit: I have followed Aaron's advice for extending the original class.  Here is my di.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference
        for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable"
        type="zzTest\zzModule\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" />
</config>
```

Here is what zzTest\zzModule\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php looks like:

```
<?php 

namespace zzTest\zzModule\Block\Product\View\Type;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable;
class Configurable extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable
{
    public function getXPPackCounts()
    {
        return 'good';
    }
}
```

Finally, I attempt to call this function from configurable.phtml in design/frontend/my/theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml .  My calling code looks like this:

`<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getXPPackCounts() ?>`

I know this phtml file is being called okay because I have other stuff on it that shows up.  But I don't receive any output from my call.  What have I setup incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plugins are not used for adding a method, they are for altering the input/output of an existing public method.

You'll need to replace the block with one that reuses the template but has a class which extends `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable` and contains your method.

In `{module_dir}/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml` :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.configurable" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block class="Your\Module\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="my.product.info.options.configurable" before="-" template="Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Aaron, I have taken the steps you suggest, however I am not able to call the functions from the configurable.phtml file.  I have added the contents of my di.xml and class extension file to the O.P. , as well as the php code I use to call the new method of the extending class.

Comment: I guess dependency injection won't work in this case because the block is being called from a layout xml and not a php constructor. Regardless, you should be able to replace the block in layout. I'll change the answer to reflect this.

Comment: When I did as you suggested, and added the xml file, I got some interesting results.  The remove directive is ignored, but a second version of the block appears on the page - in one of the blocks I get the output from the special class (a string containing "good") and the other one still doesn't work.  Also, I had to leave the preference in the di.xml or magento breaks.  Pretty confusing!

Comment: It's a mystery as to why the remove directive doesn't work in this case. This is a bit of a hack, but to get rid of that block you could create an 'afterGetHtml' plugin for the `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable` class that just returns an empty string. As for the offending preference in di.xml, try deleting the var/generation directory.

Comment: This statement is incorrect: `Plugins are not used for adding a method, they are for altering the input/output of an existing public method.`...there is an `around` listener that can be used to modify content of that function

Comment: The around listener gives you control over both the input and output of the function but does **not** modify the function itself.